# pick a color from the holocolorpicker then saved using shared preferences

Tags: android

am trying to save he color picked from the holocolorpicker and use it in another activity

before the onCreate method  in the settings activity i put this lines

```
private String SettingsTAG0 = "backcolorValue";
private SharedPreferences backcolorprefs;
private static int backcolorValue = 0;
```

after the onCreate method  in the settings activity i put this lines

```
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    ColorPicker picker0 = (ColorPicker) findViewById(R.id.backpicker);
    backcolorValue = picker0.getColor();
    Editor editor0 = backcolorprefs.edit();
    editor0.clear();
    editor0.putInt("back_colorcode", backcolorValue);
    editor0.commit();
}
```

before the onCreate method of the other activity i put this lines

```
private String SettingsTAG0 = "backcolorValue";
private SharedPreferences backcolorprefs;
private static int backcolorValue = 0;
```

in the onCreate method of the other activity i put this lines

```
backcolorprefs = getSharedPreferences(SettingsTAG0, 0);
    backcolorprefs.getInt("back_colorcode", backcolorValue);
    View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(backcolorValue);
```

i am a super newbie to android and java but i make a try but nothing is happened

any help please

Comment: use `view.setBackgroundColor(backcolorprefs.getInt("back_colorcode", backcolorValue));`

Comment: the first problem i have is that the color picked dont save

Answer (score 1):

This is how sharedpreference used:

```
// put int
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("back_colorcode", backcolorValue);
editor.commit();

// get int
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int backcolorValue = sharedpreferences.getInt("back_colorcode", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happened because you are not assigning value read from preferences to backcolorValue. This line:

```
backcolorprefs.getInt("back_colorcode", backcolorValue);
```

simply reads it and DOESN'T store in backcolorValue. Do:

```
backcolorValue = backcolorprefs.getInt("back_colorcode", backcolorValue);
```

Also, in **onColorChanged**, I don't see that you're initialising backcolorprefs, so make sure you do. Btw, for **getSharedPreferences**, you should use constant Context.MODE_PRIVATE, instead of hardcoded value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

`onColorChanged` method parameter is color code selected from ColorPicker. save same in SharedPreferences :

```
public void onColorChanged(int color) {
    Editor editor0 = backcolorprefs.edit();
    editor0.clear();
    editor0.putInt("back_colorcode", color);
    editor0.commit();
}
```

In second Activity get color code from preference and pass to `setBackgroundColor` :

```
int colorCode=backcolorprefs.getInt("back_colorcode", Color.BLACK);
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setBackgroundColor(colorCode);
```